# Reading application key/ function key passed by the caller in a Http triggered Azure function

Tags: azure-functions

I'd like to read the application key or function key passed by the caller in a Http triggered Azure function to add more permission checks in application layer. I read that application/function key is available in claims, but was unsuccessful. Appreciate if anyone share how to do this.

To add, if I dump all the claims to log, I get the claim value as "default" for the claim below. I was expecting the actual key instead of "default".

http://schemas.microsoft.com/2017/07/functions/claims/keyid : default

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the claim value returned is the key name defined in "Function keys" section and not the actual key itself that I was expecting.